# C# WPF TwoWay Bindings suddenly not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Recently I noticed that my TextBoxes aren't updating anymore with TwoWay Bindings. So if i'm changing the Property it doesn't update the text in the Textbox.

**XAML:**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="frm_Address1" x:Class="MegaCAD_Verwaltung.Address.frm_Address"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Address" Height="721" Width="1235"
        Closing="Frm_Address_OnClosing"
        ContentRendered="Frm_Address_OnContentRendered">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tc_adress" Margin="10">
            <TabItem x:Name="ti_New" Header="Neu" Height="30px">
                <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="60*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1141*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="Kunden ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_CustomerId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,18,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="200" Text="{Binding NewAddress.CustomerId, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Content="Firma" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_name_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,56,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Label Content="Kontaktperson" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,84,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.ContactPerson, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Label Content="Addresszeile 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,109,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_name_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="201" Text="{Binding NewAddress.AddressLineTwo, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <Label Content="Strasse / Nr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_Street" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.StreetName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Label Content="Land" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_StreetNr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="197,140,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.HouseNr, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Label Content="PLZ / Ort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,164,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_Plz" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="44,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.PlzNumber, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="inp_City" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="103,168,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.LocationName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btn_NewSave" Content="Button" Margin="0,10,8,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource SaveButton}" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="32" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NewAddress.SaveNewAddressCommand}"/>
                    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,266,0,10" Width="781" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.LicensesOwned, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding id}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anzahl" Width="0.3*" Binding="{Binding amount}"/>
                            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Produkt" Width="1*" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllProductsSource}}" SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding product_id}" DisplayMemberPath="name"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="WV-Ablauf" SortMemberPath="MaintenanceExpire" Width="0.7*" >
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <DatePicker IsEnabled="{Binding isActive}" SelectedDate="{Binding MaintenanceExpire, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Benutzer" Width="0.7*" Binding="{Binding user}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kommentar" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding comment}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dongle ID" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding dongle_id}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_Mail" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="178" Margin="736,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395" Grid.Column="1" RowHeaderWidth="0" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.ContactsOwned}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ContactName}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Telefon" Width="*" Binding="{Binding PhoneNumber}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="E-Mail" Width="*" Binding="{Binding EmailAddress}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_links" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="173" Margin="736,449,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395" RowHeaderWidth="0" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.LinksOwned}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Binding="{Binding Link}" Width="196" Header="Link">
                                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style>
                                        <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="OnOpenLinkInBrowser"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                            </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Comment}" Width="196" Header="Bemerkung"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <Label Content="Kontakte" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="736,18,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBox x:Name="tb_Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="178" Margin="736,266,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="395" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding NewAddress.Comment}"/>
                    <Label Content="Bemerkungen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="736,237,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.488,1.577" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cb_CountryCode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="44,196,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.AvailableCodes, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="Code" SelectedItem="{Binding NewAddress.CCode}" SelectedValue="{Binding NewAddress.CCode.Code}"/>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_Branche" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" Height="208" Margin="523,16.05,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" UseLayoutRounding="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.IndustrySectorsOwned, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding IndustrySectorId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" Header="Branche" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Width="0.75*" Header="Aktiv" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid x:Name="dg_Branche_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CanUserResizeColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" Height="208" Margin="289.5,16.05,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" UseLayoutRounding="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding NewAddress.AddressTypesOwned, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Column="1">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding AddressTypeId}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="2*" Header="Adresstyp" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Width="0.75*" Header="Aktiv" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
namespace MegaCAD_Verwaltung.Address
{
    using Data.Models;
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für frm_Address.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class frm_Address : Window
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource DataGridFillerKiller = new CancellationTokenSource();
        private CancellationTokenSource DataGridSearchKiller = new CancellationTokenSource();
        public Task DataGridFiller { get; set; }
        public Task DataGridSearch { get; set; }

        public NewAddressTab NewAddress { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<AddressForSearchGrid> AllAddresses
        {
            get { return _AllAddresses; }
            set
            {
                _AllAddresses = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllAddresses");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<AddressTypeForSearch> AllAddressTypes
        {
            get { return _allAddressTypes; }
            set
            {
                _allAddressTypes = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllAddressTypes");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<IndustrySectorForSearch> AllIndustrySectors
        {
            get { return _allIndustrySectors; }
            set
            {
                _allIndustrySectors = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllIndustrySectors");
            }
        }

        public AddressTypeForSearch SelectedAddressType { get; set; } = new AddressTypeForSearch();
        public IndustrySectorForSearch SelectedIndustrySector { get; set; } = new IndustrySectorForSearch();

        public string SearchId { get; set; }
        public string SearchName { get; set; }
        public string SearchLocation { get; set; }
        public string SearchPostal { get; set; }
        public string SearchEmail { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<AddressTypeForSearch> _allAddressTypes = new ObservableCollection<AddressTypeForSearch>();
        private ObservableCollection<IndustrySectorForSearch> _allIndustrySectors = new ObservableCollection<IndustrySectorForSearch>();

        public ICommand LoadAddressesCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand ExecuteSearchCommand { get; set; }

        private object _AllAddressLock { get; set; } = new object();
        private ObservableCollection<AddressForSearchGrid> _AllAddresses = new ObservableCollection<AddressForSearchGrid>();

        public class NewAddressTab
        {
            public Address AddressToEdit { get; set; }
            public CountryCodeEntry CCode { get; set; }

            private string _CustomerId;

            public string CustomerId
            {
                get { return _CustomerId; }
                set
                {
                    _CustomerId = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("CustomerId");
                }
            }
            public string CompanyName { get; set; }
            public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
            public string AddressLineTwo { get; set; }
            public string StreetName { get; set; }
            public string HouseNr { get; set; }
            public string PlzNumber { get; set; }
            public string LocationName { get; set; }
            public string Comment { get; set; }

            public List<CountryCodeEntry> AvailableCodes { get; set; } = new List<CountryCodeEntry>();

            public ObservableCollection<AddressTypeGrid> AddressTypesOwned { get; set; } =
                new ObservableCollection<AddressTypeGrid>();

            public ObservableCollection<IndustrySectorGrid> IndustrySectorsOwned { get; set; } =
                new ObservableCollection<IndustrySectorGrid>();

            public ObservableCollection<LinksGridEntry> LinksOwned { get; set; } =
                new ObservableCollection<LinksGridEntry>();

            public ObservableCollection<LicenseGridEntry> LicensesOwned { get; set; } =
                new ObservableCollection<LicenseGridEntry>();

            public ObservableCollection<Product> AllProducts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

            public ObservableCollection<ContactGridEntry> ContactsOwned { get; set; } =
                new ObservableCollection<ContactGridEntry>();

            public LinksGridEntry LinkGridSelectedItem { get; set; }

            public ICommand SaveNewAddressCommand { get; set; }


            private frm_Address Parent;

            public NewAddressTab(frm_Address parent)
            {
                SaveNewAddressCommand = new ActionCommand(p => SaveView());

                AddressToEdit = new Address();

                Parent = parent;

                FillFields();
            }

            public void FillFields()
            {
                GetProducts();

                GetCountryCodes();

                GetAddressTypes();

                GetIndustrySectors();
            }

            private void GetCountryCodes()
            {
                // Get Country Codes for the Combobox
                List<CountryCode> ccModels = CountryCode.All();

                foreach (var model in ccModels)
                {
                    AvailableCodes.Add(new CountryCodeEntry(new CountryCode(model.id)));
                }
            }

            private void GetAddressTypes()
            {
                //Get the addresstypes assigned to the Address
                List<AddressType> allAddressTypes = AddressType.All();

                foreach (AddressType addresstype in allAddressTypes)
                {
                    AddressTypesOwned.Add(new AddressTypeGrid(addresstype.id, false));
                }
            }

            private void GetIndustrySectors()
            {
                //Get the industry_sectors assigned to the Address
                List<IndustrySector> allIndustrySectors = IndustrySector.All();

                foreach (IndustrySector industrySector in allIndustrySectors)
                {
                    IndustrySectorsOwned.Add(new IndustrySectorGrid(industrySector.id, false));
                }
            }

            private void GetProducts()
            {
                foreach (Product product in Product.All())
                {
                    AllProducts.Add(product);
                }
            }

            private void SaveView()
            {
                //Setzt die Werte des Addressobjekts um dieses zu speichern
                AddressToEdit.customerID = new Unique<string>(CustomerId);
                AddressToEdit.company_name = new NullableString(CompanyName);
                AddressToEdit.contact_name = new NullableString(ContactPerson);
                AddressToEdit.addressline_2 = new NullableString(AddressLineTwo);
                AddressToEdit.street = new NullableString(StreetName);
                AddressToEdit.house_nr = new NullableString(HouseNr);
                AddressToEdit.postal_code = new NullableString(PlzNumber);
                AddressToEdit.location = new NullableString(LocationName);
                AddressToEdit.comment = new NullableString(Comment);
                AddressToEdit.updated_by = Properties.Settings.Default.user;

                if (CCode != null)
                {
                    AddressToEdit.fk_country_code =
                        new ForeignKey(new CountryCode(), ForeignKey.KeyType.NO_ACTION, true, CCode.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddressToEdit.fk_country_code = new ForeignKey(new CountryCode(), ForeignKey.KeyType.NO_ACTION, true, 0);
                }

                AddressToEdit.Save();

                SaveAddressTypes();

                SaveIndustrySectors();

                SaveLinks();

                SaveLicenses();

                SaveContacts();

                MessageBox.Show("Adresse wurde gespeichert!", "Erfolg!", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Information);

                ClearFields();

                string displayName = "";

                if (AddressToEdit.company_name.Value != "")
                {
                    displayName = AddressToEdit.company_name.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    displayName = AddressToEdit.contact_name.Value;
                }

                Parent.NewTab(AddressToEdit.id, displayName);
            }

            private void ClearFields()
            {
                //Clear all the Fields
                CCode = null;
                CustomerId = null;
                CompanyName = null;
                ContactPerson = null;
                AddressLineTwo = null;
                StreetName = null;
                HouseNr = null;
                PlzNumber = null;
                LocationName = null;
                Comment = null;

                LinksOwned.Clear();
                LinkGridSelectedItem = null;

                AddressTypesOwned.Clear();
                IndustrySectorsOwned.Clear();

                AvailableCodes.Clear();

                LicensesOwned.Clear();

                ContactsOwned.Clear();

                LinkGridSelectedItem = null;
            }

            private void SaveContacts()
            {
                foreach (ContactGridEntry contactGridEntry in ContactsOwned)
                {
                    new Contact()
                    {
                        contactname = new NullableString((contactGridEntry.ContactName).ToString()),
                        email = new NullableString((contactGridEntry.EmailAddress).ToString()),
                        phonenumber = new NullableString((contactGridEntry.PhoneNumber).ToString()),
                        fk_address_id = new ForeignKey(new Contact(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, AddressToEdit.id),
                        updated_by = Properties.Settings.Default.user,

                    }.Save();
                }
            }

            private void SaveLinks()
            {
                foreach (LinksGridEntry linksGridEntry in LinksOwned)
                {
                    new Link()
                    {
                        link_string = linksGridEntry.Link,
                        comment = new NullableString(linksGridEntry.Comment),
                        fk_address_id = new ForeignKey(new Address(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, AddressToEdit.id),
                        updated_by = linksGridEntry.Updated_by,

                    }.Save();
                }
            }

            private void SaveLicenses()
            {
                foreach (LicenseGridEntry licenseGridEntry in LicensesOwned)
                {
                    new License()
                    {
                        fk_address_id = new ForeignKey(new Address(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, AddressToEdit.id),
                        fk_product_id = new ForeignKey(new Product(), ForeignKey.KeyType.SET_NULL, true, licenseGridEntry.product_id),
                        amount = licenseGridEntry.amount,
                        maintenace_Expire = licenseGridEntry.maintenance_expire,
                        user = new NullableString(licenseGridEntry.user),
                        comment = new NullableString(licenseGridEntry.comment),
                        dongle_id = new NullableString(licenseGridEntry.dongle_id),
                        updated_by = Properties.Settings.Default.user,

                    }.Save();

                }
            }

            public void SaveAddressTypes()
            {
                foreach (AddressTypeGrid addressTypeGrid in AddressTypesOwned)
                {
                    List<Address_AddressType> allAddressAddressTypes = Address_AddressType.WhereAnd(
                        new[] { "fk_address_id", "fk_addresstype_id" },
                        new object[] { AddressToEdit.id, addressTypeGrid.AddressTypeId });

                    if (allAddressAddressTypes.Count == 0 && addressTypeGrid.IsActive)
                    {
                        new Address_AddressType()
                        {
                            fk_address_id = new ForeignKey(new Address(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, AddressToEdit.id),
                            fk_addresstype_id = new ForeignKey(new AddressType(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, addressTypeGrid.AddressTypeId)

                        }.Save();
                    }
                    else if (allAddressAddressTypes.Count != 0 && !addressTypeGrid.IsActive)
                    {
                        allAddressAddressTypes[0].Delete();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void SaveIndustrySectors()
            {
                foreach (IndustrySectorGrid industrySectorGrid in IndustrySectorsOwned)
                {
                    List<Address_IndustrySector> allAddressIndustrySectors = Address_IndustrySector.WhereAnd(
                        new[] { "fk_address_id", "fk_industry_sector_id" },
                        new object[] { AddressToEdit.id, industrySectorGrid.IndustrySectorId });

                    if (allAddressIndustrySectors.Count == 0 && industrySectorGrid.IsActive)
                    {
                        new Address_IndustrySector()
                        {
                            fk_address_id = new ForeignKey(new Address(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, AddressToEdit.id),
                            fk_industry_sector_id = new ForeignKey(new IndustrySector(), ForeignKey.KeyType.CASCADE, false, industrySectorGrid.IndustrySectorId)

                        }.Save();
                    }
                    else if (allAddressIndustrySectors.Count != 0 && !industrySectorGrid.IsActive)
                    {
                        allAddressIndustrySectors[0].Delete();
                    }
                }
            }

            #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            private void OnPropertyChanged(string proprtyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(proprtyName));
            }

            #endregion
        }

        private readonly ObservableCollection<ITab> tabs;

        ....
```

AFAIK i specified that it's a TwoWay binding at every TextBox. I also implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged event for the Properties / TextBoxes that where not updating.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help

EDIT: specified problem.

Comment: "TextBoxes aren't updating anymore with TwoWay Bindings" is unfortunately vague, but I did notice that `NewAddressTab` needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise its PropetyChanged event in its property setters when the property values change.

Comment: Well a few days ago it did update the text in the textbox if you changed the bound property and the other way around, this seems to not happen anymore.

Comment: TextBox TextProperty is marked as twoway by default. You don't need the mode = twoway.

Comment: That class needs to implement that interface. I haven't gone over every line of your code, but it's entirely possible that you have the same problem elsewhere. Every property which is bound, or which is part of a path in a binding, needs to raise that event, and its class needs to implement that interface (either that, or the property must be a dependency property of a DependencyObject, which I can explain in more depth if necessary). Otherwise, bindings will not update when property values change.

Comment: hi @SayHey does it work before adding TwoWay  binding , you need to add more details to answer you .

Comment: It doesn't work with or without twoway mode. Because that makes no difference. Ed is correct. No inotifypropertychanged interface means no notifications are looked for by the view. Observablecollections raise a different notification event when adding, removing or setting a given item - which could well be what is confusing Say Hey.

Comment: Also. When you post code. If you post a huge swathe of code that's easy for you to do. Copy, paste... done.  But you reduce your chances of people taking time with what you posted. Because it's not easy to pick through and work out what is happening.

Comment: Andy's got a good point about the excess code. It's hardly convenient for us to wade through acres of `<Label Content="Kunden ID" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>` which have nothing to do with bindings on text boxes. But this is your first time here, and it's much, much better to post too much code than not enough!

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help, it just didn't get that the class has to inherit INotifyPropertyChanged. After I inherited the Interface and changed the proerties to call OnPropertyChanged when set everything works as expected. Thanks a lot :)